# what happens when %x read signed char?

Tags: c, printf, specifier

[image]

i thought *(p3 + 3) will print 90 but it shows ffffff90
why does it happend?
i guess MSB is 1, and %x is for reading unsinged hexadecimal integer so it reads 90 like minus integer but it is not clear and i cant find about this problem at printf reference
https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/
is there anyone who explain this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please simplify your program down to a [mcve] and post the entire program and its output as text, not an image.  You have lots of unneeded variables and print commands.

Comment: @DavidGrayson im sorry i'll try it

Comment: In the future, please post text as text, not just as a screenshot.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `unsigned char *`.

---

In your environment,

- `char` is signed.
- `char` is 8 bits.
- Signed numbers use two's complement.

So you have a `char` with a bit pattern of 90<sub>16</sub>. In this environment, that's -112. So you are effectively doing the following:

```c
printf( "%x", (char)-112 );
```

When passing to variadric function like `printf`, the smaller integer types are implicitly promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`. So what's really happening is this:

```c
printf( "%x", (int)(char)-112 );
```

So you're passing the `int` value -112. On your machine, that has the bit pattern FF FF FF 90<sub>16</sub> (in some unknown byte order). `%x` expects an unsigned integer, and thus prints that bit pattern as-is.

Comment: If your platform (C library) supports it, you can print using `printf("%hhx\n", -112)` and the output will be 90 as desired.  See the POSIX specification for [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)
or the C standard (C11) specification for [§7.21.6.1 The `printf` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I was aware of that, but I don't like that hack. `%x` requires an unsigned number, and there's no reason to use the wrong type and try to fix it up afterwards.